# Dynamic DataGrid Headers

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I've a problem where i need to get the total number of columns, which defines the total columns. Currently i have a function which dictates the header text on the DataGrid.columns.

```
public static string ColumnHeader1 = Properties.Settings.Default.ColumnHeader1;

public void dataGridHeaders()
    {
        dataGrid.Columns[0].Header = ColumnHeader1;
        dataGrid.Columns[1].Header = ColumnHeader2;
        dataGrid.Columns[2].Header = ColumnHeader3;
        dataGrid.Columns[3].Header = ColumnHeader4;
        dataGrid.Columns[4].Header = ColumnHeader5;
        dataGrid.Columns[5].Header = ColumnHeader6;
        dataGrid.Columns[6].Header = ColumnHeader7;
        dataGrid.Columns[7].Header = ColumnHeader8;
     }
```

the string vars being read in from an xml settings file. What i'm looking to do is depending on how many strings in the xml file depicts how many columns there will be at runtime. Or adding an int var say..

```
public static int totalNumberOfColumns = 8;
```

and then iterating through a loop adding the columns.

are any of these ways possible?

Answer (score 1):

Get your column header from the XML file into a string list

```
List<string> columnHeaderList = new List<string>();
foreach (string header in XmlColumnList)
    columnHeaderList.Add(header);
```

where `XmlColumnList` is some array that is holding the values. Now add the following method which will add all the avalible column headers, as rwequired.

```
private void DataGridHeaders(List<string> headerList)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < headerList.Count; i++)
        dataGrid.Columns[i].Header = headerList[i];
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
            var xmlSample = @"<DataGridColumnsHeader>
                            <ColumnHeaderText>Name</ColumnHeaderText>
                            <ColumnHeaderText>Country</ColumnHeaderText>
                            <ColumnHeaderText>Phone</ColumnHeaderText>
                          </DataGridColumns>";

        var counter = 0;
        var elementCount = XDocument.Load(new System.IO.StringReader(xmlSample)).XPathSelectElements("//ColumnHeaderText").Count();
        foreach (var element in XDocument.Load(new System.IO.StringReader(xmlSample)).XPathSelectElements("//ColumnHeaderText"))
        {
            dataGrid.Columns[counter].Header = element.Value;
            counter++;
        }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've done it a different way.. and quite possibly the laziest way possible.. reading a full string with all the values into an array and splitting them.